# Adding chain to gnosis UI

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, truffle

I just followed steps to add new chain using this repo:
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure

But when I click on [image]

Nothing happens.
In order to bring up this safe-infrastructure and gnosis ui... this is the only way (using repo and it's docker composer)?

Regards,
Juliano

Answer (score 0):

This is related to AWS Load Balance, need to create one target group for 8000 (Admin API) and other for 8080(UI)